# jmeter regex: extracting ID which is in the beginning based on search text at the end of the search target string

Tags: regex, jmeter

Can someone please help me extract the dynamic number (eg: 186) in the following string based on the text in the "caption" (eg: dditional Information) which is unique. I need this to use in the jmeter regular expression extractor. I have tried this:

```
}}},"(.+?)":"immediate":true,"htmlContentAllowed":true,"height":"24.0px","width":"100.0%","tabIndex":5,"styles":["iw-child"],"caption":"<NOBR><u><u>A<\/u><\/u>dditional Information<\/NOBR>"}
```

**Search Target:**

```
"185":{"childFlowData":{"186":{"widthUnit":null,"maxWidthUnit":null,"width":0,"maxWidth":0,"consumeRemainingWidth":true}},"height":"100.0%","width":"100.0%","registeredEventListeners":["lClick"],"childData":{"186":{"expandRatio":0,"alignmentBitmask":5}}},**"186":{"immediate":true,"htmlContentAllowed":true,"height":"24.0px","width":"100.0%","tabIndex":5,"styles":["iw-child"],"caption":"<NOBR><u><u>A<\/u><\/u>dditional Information<\/NOBR>"},**"88":{"enabled":false,"immediate":true,"text":"<NOBR>2<\/NOBR>","width":"100.0%","styles":["iw-child"],"contentMode":"HTML"},"89":{"childFlowData":{"90":{"widthUnit":null,"maxWidthUnit":null,"width":0,"maxWidth":0,"consumeRemainingWidth":true}},"height":"100.0%","width":"100.0%","childData":{"90":{"expandRatio":0,"alignmentBitmask":5}}},"116":{"enabled":false,"immediate":true,"text":"<NOBR>RAYMOND A TESTER<\/NOBR>",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test data there are 3 occurrences of 186, so providing 3 regexes as they have prefix strings

For 1st occurrence of 186,

```
:{"childFlowData":{"(\d+)":
```

Provide match no : 1 so this is will match 186 else it will match next occurrence 90.

For 2nd occurrence of 186,

```
,"childData":{"(\d+)":
```

Again provide match no : 1 so this will match 186 else it will match 90.

For 3rd occurrence for 186 which you have tried,

```
}}},\*\*"(\d+)":
```

here only one match is present, you can specify match no as 1 or 0 for random if only one occurrence is present in data.

Comment: Thanks for you help. The 3rd occurrence you mentioned above worked for me. This is what I have at the end which retrieves the number pertaining to the caption "dditional Information" ====>>        }}},"(\d+)":{"immediate":true,"htmlContentAllowed":true,"height":"24.0px","width":"100.0%","tabIndex":5,"styles":\["iw-child"],"caption":"<NOBR><u><u>A<\\/u><\\/u>dditional Information<\\/NOBR>"}

Comment: glad it worked :) Accept/Upvote the answer if it was helpful to you